# What's the best deployment strategy when using Subversion?

Tags: svn, deployment

I have SVN setup on my local dev box, my live server has only outbound svn only. What's the best way to upload or commit the changes only to the live server. I have to upload the whole code base now. I don't like to follow the way anymore. Please suggest me a good way to have updates committed or uploaded to the live server.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are people voting to close? seems like a legit, interesting question...

Comment: The vote appear to be to migrate to SU. Presumably they think that this is a "How do I use my program?" question. I'm leaning that way myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't touch the Subversion server instance on your production server, you have a couple of options:

- Publish the code elsewhere, then use the Subversion client on your production server to pull down a copy of the code from the published location. (Make sure you use `svn export`, not `svn checkout`, so that you don't get `.svn` directories scattered all over, or else protect your `.svn` directories in some way.)
- Use a post-commit hook on your local development environment to push the code to the server (for example, via FTP). Every time you commit, you'll trigger a push to production. You'll probably want something more fine-grained -- for example, a common practice is to trigger this push whenever a tag is committed that includes the word "release".

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to use

```
svn export
```

make sure that your .svn directories are not web accessible. Otherwise one could potentially obtain your source code via the SVN files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
  ErrorDocument 403 "Access Forbidden"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the "outbound" SVN only but SVN over HTTP using Apache is working fine for my configuration. Most tutorials out there will get you started in minutes.

The rest are "easy", if you are familiar with SVN.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) to trigger an `svn export`.